# Migrate Spring portlet to web mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, portlet, portal, spring-portlet-mvc

I was assigned to restructure an existing project. This project is a portal with two features.

1. allow users single sign on to view brief information from other existing web apps
2. managing users through other web app's API/databases

This project uses [Spring Portlet MVC 3](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/portlet.html), [eXo portal container](http://www.exoplatform.com/company/en/products), and [CAS single sign on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service) (each are standalone web apps).

As time goes by, we find that the first feature needs to be shut down. This leaves single sign on,  allowing users to click a link and reach other systems. We want to convert this project to a normal web app using Spring MVC to get rid of the heaviness of eXo platform. Can anyone exposed to this situation please give a suggestion? Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: How are you currently handling Single Sign On? Spring Security has facilities to do this and integrates well with Spring MVC web apps.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a pretty straightforward conversion. Spring MVC and Spring Security will facilitate your Single Sign-On. It's going to require some grunt work to put to the pieces together, the most of which will be configuring the Spring Security file. Luckily you will only have to do this once. Spring MVC is a breeze though. It is a fantastic MVC implementation that has tons of flexibility. I've never regretted using it.